# PHP OSX ODBC + MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

Hi 2 days I trying setup PHP + MSSQL under OS X 10.8.2 server but no success yet.

I have tried install FreeTDS, compiling mssql.so, successfully loaded it with PHP,
but function mssql_connect(server,user,pass); always return false.

also I tried using standart ODBC Administrator to configure drivers settings,

my odbc.ini looks like this:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = 1

[ODBC Data Sources]
MSSQL = MSSQL

[MSSQL]
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
Description = MSSQL
username    = su
password    = 1234
```

but no success with odbc_connect();

also tried DSN less method

```
<?php
$connection = odbc_connect( 'DRIVER={MSSQL};SERVER=192.168.1.94\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=NMSDb', 'sa', '1234' ) or die('Error')
?>
```

I can successfully connect to SQL from Navicat using host 192.168.1.94\SQLEXPRESS, user sa and password 1234

but how do this from php? usually I use MySQL there is no problem with that, but MS SQL is nightmare